# How do I paginate a Stream ranked feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I was pretty deep into integrating Stream into my existing pagination implementation (which is also used for paginating non-activity data stored in MySQL) when I came across this line in the Stream documentation under "[Custom Ranking](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#custom_ranking)":

> Please note: `offset` and `id_lt` cannot be used to read ranked feeds. Use `score_lt` for pagination instead.

This seems to be the only mention of `score_lt` in the docs. I can't find it discussed anywhere else, nor can I find an example of what its value should be. Should it be the same UUID I would use for `id_lt` if I were paginating a non-ranked feed? Or is it meant to be a score value of some kind that would be returned only by a ranked feed?

Normally I'd just try it and see, but ranked feeds are only available to paid plans and I'm still evaluating Stream.

This could have significant implications for how I implement pagination though, since I do want to be able to use ranked feeds in the future if I move forward with Stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When retrieving activities from a ranked feed using a specific ranking config, each activity will include a `score` attribute. You can use the `score_lt` to paginate through the items in the ranked feed (along with the `limit` parameter).

*(When paginating through items on non-ranked feeds, we usually recommend using the `id_lt` parameter, which will just return activities by creation date, in chronological order from most-recent to least-recent. However, since older content in a ranked feed might be ranked higher than newer content, we have to paginate and order via the `score` attribute.)*

--

Whenever you create a ranked feed, you'll create at least one ranked feed config. I'm going to name my ranked feed config `ranked-feed-config-one` (you can have as many as you'd like) which will look something like this:

```
{
    "score": "decay_linear(time) * popularity ^ 0.5",
    "defaults": {
        "popularity": 1
    }
}
```

Whenever you send a new activity into stream, you'll also provide an optional `popularity` parameter. (If you don't provide one, `popularity` will default to `1`.)

Then, whenever you retrieve activities from the ranked feed, you can specify what ranking config you'd like to use (`ranked-feed-config-one`), like this:

```
someFeed.get({ ranking: 'ranked-feed-config-one' })
```

Each activity will be returned with (and ordered by) a `score` attribute. You'll save the last `score` attribute, and use that when supplying the `score_lt` parameter for future pagination calls.

--

Hopefully that helps clear things up! Let me know if there's anything else I can help answer for you.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like the `score` value of an activity in any given ranked feed is entirely dynamic, which makes sense. But if I can only paginate a ranked feed by a dynamic score value, that means I can never request ranked activities after a specific _activity_ id that I previously stored. Is this accurate?

Comment: ( @RyanGrove ) You can paginate ranked feeds (or more accurately, "feeds with ranking methods enabled") using `id_lt` & `offset` **only if** you make the request the **without** a ranking method - e.g. `someFeed.get({ id_lt: "uuid1234" })` instead of `someFeed.get({ ranking: "ranked-feed-config-one", score_lt: "10" })`. That way, you'll still be able to get a list of activities from the feed via ID, but they'll be ordered chronologically (most recent to least recent) instead of by `score`.

Comment: @KenHoff: This really confuses me... What if there are multiple activities with same score... hypothetical, lets say all activities in 2 pages have same rank...

Now how Will I use score_lt ? 
without missing actiivties...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Limit & Offset Pagination`.

`someFeed.get({limit:20, offset:20})`